# Message lost when client connection lost suddenly in ejabberd

Tags: xmpp, ejabberd, ejabberd-module, ejabberd-hooks

I'm new to ejabberd. my problem is that when the wifi connection is lost suddenly, the messages are lost for few seconds. according to the [Link](https://www.ejabberd.im/faq/tcp) I have enabled Stream Management and resend_on_timeout set to true and enabled mod_ping with ping_interval: 10 But still Im missing messages. 
 Here the port 5222 settings
 `port: 5222
    module: ejabberd_c2s
    certfile: "/home/salu/ejabberd-16.09/conf/server.pem"
    starttls: true
    stream_management: true
    resend_on_timeout: true
    ## To enforce TLS encryption for client connections,
    ## use this instead of the "starttls" option:
    ## starttls_required: true
    ##
    ## Custom OpenSSL options
    ##
    protocol_options:
      - "no_sslv3"
    ##   - "no_tlsv1"
    max_stanza_size: 65536
    shaper: c2s_shaper
    access: c2s` 
 And mod_ping settings 
 `mod_ping:
    send_pings: true
    ping_interval: 10
    timeout_action: kill`
Can anyone tell what is the problem How can I solve this?

Comment: you have to enable stream management client side also.

Comment: check this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17424254/ejabberd-online-status-when-user-loses-connection/22606829#22606829

Comment: @SunilSingh For sender i am using client PSI in my pc and for receiver I am using client Xabber which i found in playstore. I have checked XML Console in PSI it has enabled stream management with <enable xmlns='urn:xmpp:sm:3' resume='true'/> and server response <enabled xmlns='urn:xmpp:sm:3' id='some-long-sm-id' resume='true'/> Is something else I need to implement